# What are some fungus or rot-based spells?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e, content-identification

I'm homebrewing a sort of rot druid for a campaign, and need some help finding spells that fit the motif.

Comment: Welcome, Bob. I think you may be unfamiliar with the purpose of SE, but workshopping ideas isn't really our deal. We instead aim to have clear answers to narrow questions. I think you'll be better served taking this question to a forum and folks can spitball ideas with you.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical This isn’t really workshopping ideas, it’s a content-identification question that’s been mistagged. It *might* be Too Broad, but I kind of doubt it? I don’t know 4e that well, but it’d surprise me if there were an unreasonably large number of such spells.

Comment: @KRyan 4e doesn't even really have spells at all in the sense that other versions do. Some class' powers are called spells, but that's purely cosmetic. And since nearly all powers/spells are class-specific, this needs to be narrowed down to a particular class at the very least.

Comment: Closed as too broad, since it is [requesting a menu of options](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7584/1204). As Oblivious Sage has mentioned, I'm concerned D&D 4e's handling of powers also makes this problematic: almost any power can be reflavored as fungus- or rot-themed, and almost any power is on the table here, so we wouldn't know when the list is really complete. Instead this question probably better suits [a forum, such as one of these of which we've gathered a list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449).

Comment: @ObliviousSage The entire premise is to create a new class, so what class powers are associated with officially is irrelevant. And the quibble about powers vs. spells doesn’t seem to add anything here.

Comment: @doppelgreener It doesn’t seem to be requesting options off of a list, so much as a complete list. We have a lot of successful questions of that sort. And refluffing something else would not make for a good answer to the question.

Comment: @KRyan IIRC 4e made reskinning a RAW rule, so the answer is potentially every/any power. This won’t have a quality outcome if reopened; this request is something SE does poorly and forums do well, which is the ur-reason for every other more specific site guideline or rule.